# C++11 enable_if on return type of subscript operator of template parameter

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I'm working with vector classes containing either integer or floating point types. I'd like to choose one or the other function template accordingly, but the only way to deduce the type is through the subscript operator [].

Is there a way to use `enable_if<is_integral< ...` on the return type of the [] operator of the template parameter?
Something like:

```
template<class V, typename enable_if<is_integral<V::operator[]>::value, int>::type = 0>
int MyFunc(V vec)
{ return vec[0]; }

template<class V, typename enable_if<!is_integral<V::operator[]>::value, int>::type = 0>
int MyFunc(V vec)
{ return ceil(vec[0]); }
```

Comment: `decltype(declval<V>()[0])`

Comment: @appleapple, this solution is not reliable. It doesn't work for `std::vector<bool>`, for instance. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Enlico true, well nothing is really reliable if you know nothing about the target type, `operator[]` may not even accept `int`.

Comment: @appleapple, this is inaccurate. Relying on `operator[]` means you're making assumptions on an implementation detail. Relying on `begin` member function means you're assuming the `V` uses a common and well known API. After all, if you're sending it to a function that expects it to be a kind of "collection", it must provide a method to access the elements. So the assumption boils down to that function being named `begin` and not `beginner` or anything else.

Comment: @Enlico yes, it always need assumption, that's my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Some general suggestion

I would avoid `using namespace std` which your code implies (almost) that you use.

You can shorten and make more readable `std::enable_if<T>::type` and `std::is_integral<T>::value` by writing them as `std::enable_if_t<T>` and `std::is_integral_v<T>` respectively (search for "Helper types" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), for instance).

### The answer to your question

**You need to apply `operator[]` to something**

What you really want to ask is if the items in the object of type `V` can be accessed via `[]`, so you want to check whether something like `V{}[0]` is valid, so you would write something like this (as to why `std::decay_t` is needed, see note (¹)):

```cpp
template<class V, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<decltype(V{}[0])>>, int> = false>
```

**But `V` might be not default constructible**

If you want to support types `V` without assuming that they are default constructible you can use `std::declval` to "pretend" you create a value of that type (here `std::decay_t` is needed for the same reason as above):

```cpp
template<class V, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<V>()[0])>>, int> = false>
```

**And `operator[]` could return some proxy to the actual entities in `V`**

In general `operator[]` doesn't return an object of the type which is "conceptually" the type stored in the container; for instance, for `std::vector<bool>`, `operator[]` doesn't return a `bool&`, but a proxy type²; in those cases, you really want to rely on the `value_type` type alias stored in the container:

```cpp
template<class V, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<typename V::value_type>, int> = false>
```

**Something might be not `value_type`-equipped but only provide `.begin()`/`.end()`**

As a last improvement, we can also remove the assumption that the `V` has a `value_type` member alias (which is true for STL container), and simply require that it has a `begin` member function (STL container have it too), and make use of `ranges::iter_value_t`³:

```cpp
template<class V, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<ranges::iter_value_t<decltype(std::declval<V>().begin())>>, int> = 0>
```

Notice that

```cpp
ranges::iter_value_t<decltype(std::declval<V>().begin())>
```

is in general not the same same thing as

```cpp
std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<V>().begin())>
```

a case of when they are different being, again, `std::vector<bool>`.

---

¹ `std::vector<int>::operator[]`, for instance, returns `int&`, not `int`, and `int&` is *not* integral:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_integral_v<int&>); // fails
```

² For instance:

```cpp
// this passes
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<std::vector<int>>()[0])>>);
// this doesn't!
static_assert(std::is_same_v<bool, std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<std::vector<bool>>()[0])>>);
// with my compiler, this one does pass
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::_Bit_reference, std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<std::vector<bool>>()[0])>>);
```

³ `ranges::iter_value_t` is from the header `#include <range/v3/iterator/access.hpp>` of the [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) library. The documentation of that library is close to crap, so you can refer the doc of the analagous C++20 functionality on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t).

Comment: Amazing answer! It was the `std::decay_t<decltype(V{}[0])` part I was missing. Oh, and `std::is_integral_v<T>` only appeared in C++17. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `std::vector::value_type`?

```
template<class V, typename enable_if<is_integral<typename V::value_type>::value, int>::type = 0> 
int MyFunc(V vec)
{ return vec[0]; }

template<class V, typename enable_if<!is_integral<typename V::value_type>::value, int>::type = 0> 
int MyFunc(V vec)
{ return ceil(vec[0]); }
```